# I'm having a problem with getting this webs crawler to initiate on django. There is an error in terminal when I enter "python manage.py runserver"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, web-crawler

Error:

> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
> line 136, in check_apps_ready
> raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.") django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Here is the code for: settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'news.apps.NewsConfig',
    'news.models.Headline.NewsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Here is the code for: apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class NewsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'news'
```

Here is the code for: models.py

```
from django.db import models


from django.db import models
class Headline(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    url = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

This one finally is for: views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSoup
from news.models import Headline

def scrape(request):
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers = {"User-Agent": "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"}
    url = "https://www.theonion.com/"

    content = session.get(url, verify=False).content
    soup = BSoup(content, "html.parser")
    News = soup.find_all('div', {"class":"curation-module__item"})
    for artcile in News:
        main = artcile.find_all('a')[0]
        link = main['href']
        image_src = str(main.find('img')['srcset']).split(" ")[-4]
        title = main['title']
        new_headline = Headline()
        new_headline.title = title
        new_headline.url = link
        new_headline.image = image_src
        new_headline.save()
    return redirect("../")



def news_list(request):
    headlines = Headline.objects.all()[::-1]
    context = {
        'object_list': headlines,
    }
    return render(request, "news/home.html", context)
```

Comment: What's up with these two apps in the `INSTALLED_APPS`: `news.apps.NewsConfig` and `news.models.Headline.NewsConfig`? Remove them. The second one is probably creating the issue.

Comment: ... and instead of that add `news` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`.